# How to freeze top row in SAS tagset?

Tags: sas

I tested the `tagset`

```
ods tagsets.tableeditor file="c:\temp.html"
    options(pageheight="300"
            pagewidth="35%"
            frozen_headers="yes"
            frozen_rowheaders="yes"
            );

proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
```

However, this does not actually freeze the headers. I can't even see the difference . These two lines do not freeze headers the way it is done in excel `frozen_headers="yes"  frozen_rowheaders="yes"`

**Is there any option that would `freeze top row` the way it is done in excel ?**

Comment: What browser are you using?  I believe I read somewhere that it is only supported in IE.

Comment: i tried Chrome, IE it all the same